# What is this mechanism/devices called and how do I connect two devices using it?

Tags: networking

Someone asked me for help with the following problem. In the router side the ethernet cable is connected as follows to the wall.

[wall connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p9kD.jpg)

There is another device which allows the those connections to be used in different parts of the house, shown below.

[the device I don't know the name of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axtpA.jpg)

As shown there are only two connections on the wall at the router. This means that the internet can be used only in two locations of the house.

I saw [this item](https://www.amazon.de/Splitter-MACTISICAL-Netzwerk-Verl%C3%A4ngerungen-Connector/dp/B077PT7L6K/ref=asc_df_B077PT7L6K/?tag=googshopde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=309951437972&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=2435754605104507722&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9044409&hvtargid=pla-754725802072&psc=1&th=1&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=62023944376&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=309951437972&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=2435754605104507722&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9044409&hvtargid=pla-754725802072) on Amazon which shows [something similar](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41wlcfeUfEL._AC_SY400_.jpg). Would that work in my case? That is, use one of those at the router and another one at the device?

Also, can you tell me what the correct names are for those different parts I have described? The connection the wall, the device on the second image, the outlets at different rooms etc.

Comment: The relationship bteween the different components you’ve shown is not very clear. The device on your wall which you don’t inow the name of looks like a straight-through connector (a kind of very simple patch panel). It looks like there are only 4 cables connected to it, but 8 cables come out (the darker cables at the top). Where are those dark cables going and where do the cables going into the bottom of the “patch panel” come from? The device on Amazon is a splitter but those have some restrictions (the most important one is that the maximum speed is 100Mbps). You might not need them.

Answer (score 0):

> There is another device which allows the those connections to be used in different parts of the house, shown below.

Difficult to say with the cover on, but it's probably just a patchfield - the cables on the top, which go through the rooms with LAN plugs, are connected to the plugs below.

> This means that the internet can be used only in two locations of the house.

So you need to buy a [switch](https://geizhals.de/?cat=switchgi&asd=on&asuch=switch) (or a router with an integrated switch, an old second-hand one will do), and connect it up to the patchfield. Then you'll have "internet" everywhere.